# Using a single browser window when debugging many ASP.NET Core web app projects in a single solution

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, debugging, .net-core, browser

I have a Visual Studio solution with three web app projects, and a Blazor server project. I've configured the solution with multiple startup project, so when I start the debugging all of them starts.

Everything works fine, except for the fact that Visual Studio opens a new browser window for every project; instead I'd like to have a single browser window, with a tab for every project that I'm debugging.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior?

Comment: probably not as they each need their own debugging port to hook into the browser.  That would be browser-session-wide methinks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go `Tools` menu => Options => Project and Solutions => Web Projects, then `Uncheck` setting called: **Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops**

[image]

`Uncheck` it and click OK, after your configured the solution with multiple startup project, then you can  have a single browser window, with a tab for every project that you are debugging.

result:

[image]